# Capture 3rd param output of $.deferred in a .fail situation

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm using this code to capture jsonp errors and it's working great but not when it's called like this.

```
this.promise = this.model.fetch();
.
.
.
.fail(_.bind(function(collection, response, options) {
   console.log('response', response);  //timeout
   console.log('options', options);  //timeout rather than object
})
```

On the other code, we're not using .fail but error: and I do get the object on the 3rd param.

Btw, this is a jsonp magic hack since it deletes the value in window object when there is an error. Also, the timeout error is intentionally being executed.

Then inside error callback, I have this code to capture it

```
if (options.jsonpCallback.indexOf('callback_') !== -1 ) {
  // jsonp magic code here
}
```

This doesn't work .fail because the value of options is just a string which is the statusText. The value is "timeout"

Comment: What do you `_.bind` to?

Comment: Bergi, I fixed it this morning. I removed bind and declared var self = this on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `$.ajax` error callback you should be able to get the options by referencing `this` inside the callback, assuming you don't re-bind `this`:

```
.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
   console.log('options', this);
})
```